# AWS Secrets Manager: Credential is missing

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to access private information with my React application from Secrets Manager but when I do I get a credentials missing error.

I do have the aws SDK installed and I've tried setting up and IAM account with all privileges but it hasn't solved the problem. I will greatly appreciate your help, especially because my description of the problem is lacking detail. Below is the code that is the source of the error, the error is thrown at line 19 (response = await client.send).

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  SecretsManagerClient,
  GetSecretValueCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager";

const secret_name = "deckstatistics/firebase";

const initializeFirebase = async () => {
  const client = new SecretsManagerClient({
    region: "us-west-2",
  });

  let response;
  console.error(client.config.credentials);

  try {
    response = await client.send(
      new GetSecretValueCommand({
        SecretId: secret_name,
        VersionStage: "AWSCURRENT",
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }

  const secret = response.SecretString;

  console.log(secret);
```

Comment: Where is your application running -- on an EC2 instance or on your own computer?

Comment: For missing AWS API credentials, if your application is running on an EC2 instance (or ECS task, EKS node etc), you should attach an appropriate IAM role to it. AWS SDK and its relative tools have the capability retrieving credentials from a metadata endpoint provided by each EC2 instance. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

Comment: (cont'd) if your application is running on an on-premise or non-AWS server, you should put AWS API credentials readily accessible from the application; you can set up your organization's IdP to generate temporary credentials, or you can put a long-term credentials (e.g. IAM user access key) into somewhere safe and restricted in the server.